# PHP - Download xlsx from url and save on server

Tags: php, download, request, xlsx

May you help me with saving `xlsx` Japan statistic file on the server while using PHP. I am using the function below and it works for `xls` files.
I tried multiple ways:
-file_put_content saves with 0 bytes or 12 bytes with HTML tags instead of excel data
-curl 0 bytes
-request code down below doesn't save files at all.

I want to download and save this file:
https://www.esri.cao.go.jp/jp/stat/di/1007ci2.xlsx

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you,
Filip

```
function Request($url,$File="",$Method='POST',$data=null, $optional_headers = null,$Debug=0)
{
            $params = array('http' => array('method' => $Method));
            $optional_headers.="Accept:application/pdf;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch,br\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";

            $optional_headers.="Cache-Control:max-age=0\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Connection:keep-alive\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0  AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) SepidarBrowser/1.0.100.52 Safari/536.5\r\n";
            if ($data !== null) {
                   $params['http']['content'] = $data;
            }                              
            if ($optional_headers !== null) {
                   $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
            }
            $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
            $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx); 
            if (!$fp) {
                    return false;                     
            }
            $response= @stream_get_meta_data($fp);
            $out['header'] = $response['wrapper_data'];
            $out['body']='';
            if($File!=""){
                $fout = @fopen($File, 'w+');
            }
            while(!@feof($fp)){
                  $buffering=@fread($fp,1024*8);
                 // echo "***************\n".strlen($buffering)."\n".$buffering."\n***********************";
                  if($buffering==''){break;}
                  if($File!=""){
                      @fwrite($fout,$buffering);
                      if($Debug==1)echo strlen($buffering)."-->Download And Stored IN".$File;
                  }
                  $out['body'] .=$buffering;
            } 
            if(trim(@$out['header']['Content-Encoding'])=='deflate'){
                $out['body']=gzinflate($out['body']);
            }
            fclose($fp);
            return $out;
}





$url = 'https://www.esri.cao.go.jp/jp/stat/di/1007ci2.xlsx';
Request($url,dirname(__FILE__).'/Japan.xls','GET');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple curl function that you can re-use then the download of this file is quite easy. You will need to download a copy of `cacert.pem` - [you can find this here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) - save to your webserver and edit the path given below to suit.

```
function curl( $url, $options=array(), $headers=array() ){

    # EDIT this to suit...
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';

    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    }

    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );

    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }
    if( $headers && is_array( $headers ) ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    }
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    curl_close( $curl );
    return $res;
}




/* Create the name and path for the saved file */
$saveto='c:/temp/1007ci2.xlsx';

/* begin writing to a stream */
$fp=fopen( $saveto, 'w' );

/* fetch this url */
$url='https://www.esri.cao.go.jp/jp/stat/di/1007ci2.xlsx';

/* indicate we wish to download a file and save it to the stream already created */
$options=array(
    CURLOPT_FILE    =>  $fp
);

/* do the download */
$res=curl( $url, $options );

/* all ok? */
if( $res->info->http_code==200 ){
    echo "OK";
}

/* close the file pointer */
fclose( $fp );
```

Comment: Thanks RamRaider. It downloaded the file however with html tags inside not excel data - file is 12 KB instead of

Comment: not when I ran it it did not. This downloaded the file perfectly and it is open now in Excel for me to view.

Comment: Ok the thing is im using old PHP 5.4.8 and OpenSSL/0.9.8i      I am getting ... do not support TLS1.2 or disable TLS1.2 in your settings in this downloaded file.

Comment: Then you should kick your admin in the ass to update the PHP environment.The end-of-life of this version was September 14, 2015!

Comment: Forcing the above function to use a specific version of TLS support ( specifically `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0` ) yields 
 `"The Cabinet Office website has always been encrypted (TLS1.2) since November 29, 2018, and the URL has been changed to "https" as shown below."` ~ so it looks like there might not be much you can do to circumvent the issue other than an upgrade.